# CORBA/iiop issue during migration to websphere liberty profile

Tags: naming, corba, iiop, websphere-liberty

I had some issues migrating a webapp from `WAS 5.1` to Liberty Profile caused probably by the assence of **CORBA/iiop** services.

Does `BOOTSTRAP_PORT` still exists in liberty profile? Can someone figure out what to do? I receive this exception in `messages.log`:

```
[6/17/13 18:36:59:162 CEST] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.Incident                    I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.ws.naming.jcache.CacheEntryNotFoundException: Entry "IIOP_DEFAULT_ROOT" not found in cache. com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal 367" at ffdc_13.06.17_18.36.59.0.log
[6/17/13 18:36:59:404 CEST] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.Incident                    I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Could not obtain an initial context due to a communication failure. Since no provider URL was specified, the default provider URL of "corbaloc:iiop:1.0@debian.localdomain:2809/NameService" was used.  Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  Possible causes other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:host=debian.localdomain,port=2809  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3586  completed: No] com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext 487" at ffdc_13.06.17_18.36.59.1.log
[6/17/13 18:36:59:410 CEST] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory                     W NMSV0602E: Naming Service unavailable. A communications error occurred.
[6/17/13 18:36:59:410 CEST] 0000001a SystemErr                                                    R javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Could not obtain an initial context due to a communication failure. Since no provider URL was specified, the default provider URL of "corbaloc:iiop:1.0@debian.localdomain:2809/NameService" was used.  Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.  Possible causes other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server include the network environment and workstation network configuration. [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:host=debian.localdomain,port=2809  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3586  completed: No]
```

Thanks and best regards,

Gianluca.

Answer (score 1):

Liberty profile does not currently support RMI/IIOP.  If you need that feature, I recommend using the [RFE process](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181).